# Constraint Layout Issues

Tags: android, responsive-design, android-constraintlayout

UI with constraint layout shows good on Android Studio, but become irregular and scattered once I build and test on mobile. And when change my constraint layout to relative or linear layout, my design works perfectly. So, whats so good in constraint layout then if we can't code properly in it. Here is my code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="143dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="143dp"
            android:text="@string/booking_done_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="56dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/booking_done_sub_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="95dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_booking_done_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hotelBookNowBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/button_horizontal_padding"
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="353dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewSummaryView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/view_full_summary"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="425dp" />

        <android.support.constraint.Group
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tools` namespace attributes enable design-time features that are only used in layout editor. The value of `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY` will have no effect on the `View` at runtime.

When a `View` is missing proper constraints, the layout editor will display a warning about it. However, in your case you have ignored these warnings by setting `tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"` for your `Views`. You have only set horizontal constraints for your `Views` but the vertical ones are missing.

In order to set constraints for a `View` in the layout editor you need to click on the circles at the edges of the `View` and drag them towards other `Views` or the edge of the parent. The constraints can also be set directly in the `XML` by using appropriate attributes. The full list can be found in the [ConstraintLayout documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and it turns out all the views you workin on has to be constraint. For example if you have a button at the bottom/middle of the layout and you want to stay in that place you need to use constraint to both side of the layout and bottom. Android studio give you a warning about this.